# Analytic solution of the convolution of two discoutinous c.d.f s

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, convolution

I have a c.d.f of variable X with a mass point at the end point,

$$F(x) =
\begin{cases}
0 & x<a,\\
1-\frac{m}{x+m-a} & a\le x < r-a,\\
1 & x\ge r-a.
\end{cases}
$$
where m>0. Is it possible to get the analytic solution for the c.d.f of Y=X+X?

Thank you.

Comment: $X + X =2X$.  Or do you mean the sum of two **independent** random variables with this cdf?

Comment: Hi, I mean  the sum of two independent random variables with F(\cdot).

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, let's translate and scale so $a=0$ and $r=1$.  One way to realize a random variable $X$ with your cdf is to have $X = B + (1-B) Y$ for independent random variables $B$ and $Y$, where $B$ is Bernoulli with $P(B = 1) = m/(m+1)$ and $Y$ is  continuous  with cdf
$$F_Y(x) = \cases{0 & if $x \le 0$\cr
   (m+1) F_X(x) =  \dfrac{(m+1) x}{x + m} & if $0 \le x \le 1$\cr
            1 & if $x \ge 1$\cr}$$
and density 
$$f_Y(y) = \dfrac{m^2+m}{(x+m)^2} \ \mbox{for } 0 < x < 1, \ 0\ \mbox{otherwise}$$
Let $X_1 = B_1 + (1-B_1) Y_1$ and $X_2 = B_2 + (1-B_2) Y_2$ where $B_1, Y_1, B_2, Y_2$ are independent, so $X_1$ and $X_2$ have these distributions and are independent.  Then $X_1 + X_2 = B_1 + B_2 + (1-B_1) Y_1 + (1-B_2) Y_2$.
You can compute probabilities for $X_1 + X_2$ by conditioning on $B_1$ and $B_2$.  For example, given $B_1 = B_2 = 0$, $X_1 + X_2 = Y_1 + Y_2$.  The latter has a distribution which can be computed using some rather tedious integrals.